# gContextMenu.saveLink() function in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Does anyone know the source code of mentioned function? FYI it's the function which implements feature 'save link as..' in Firefox browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DXR](http://dxr.mozilla.org/) and [MXR](http://mxr.mozilla.org/) are your friends (short of just grabbing the code; it is open source, after all).

After searching for `saveLink`:

- http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js#1255
- http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js#1255
- Mercurial reference: http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e743fd8c57ed/browser/base/content/nsContextMenu.js#l1255

Also, in [a browser context scratchpad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Scratchpad#Running_Scratchpad_in_the_browser_context):

```
console.log(nsContextMenu.prototype.saveLink.toSource());
```

Result

```
"(function () {
    var doc =  this.target.ownerDocument;
    var linkText;
    // If selected text is found to match valid URL pattern.
    if (this.onPlainTextLink)
      linkText = this.focusedWindow.getSelection().toString().trim();
    else
      linkText = this.linkText();
    urlSecurityCheck(this.linkURL, this._unremotePrincipal(doc.nodePrincipal));

    this.saveHelper(this.linkURL, linkText, null, true, doc);
  })"
```

and so on... (although, you'll need to know that `gContextMenu` is an instance of `nsContextMenu`, which you can find out in MXR, ...)

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the tips.